# Trying to visualize country wise report using d3 geo chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a country-wise revenue split up report, I am planning to visualize it with d3.

The drill down would be like region and then countries. I thought it would be cool to visualize it with a map. Are there any examples or 'how to' blogs out there?

Comment: A treemap would also be a good choice, check [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) out (also by Mike).  As for map tutorials there's [Scott Murray's excellent book](http://alignedleft.com/work/d3-book) and also [d3 noobs](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html) examples and of course [Jason Davies](http://www.jasondavies.com/maps/) for more advanced stuff - Jason is one of the main contributors to the D3 library.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. is there any interactive map examples? any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki) which is from Mike Bostock (same guy as D3).

There are a number of examples but I recommend you start first looking at [Let's make a map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) which includes using it with D3. Whilst it is not US states it will get you started on the concepts you will need to use it.

Once you have got the basics you can then look at some of the more advanced examples listed in the [gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Gallery).

Comment: Thanks friend.. i sorted it out :)